# MongoError: not master

Tags: node.js, mongodb, driver

I am trying to connect node.js app to MongoDB having replica set but it's throwing an error when any write operations are performed.

It throws MongoError: not master.

It tries to write on secondary mongo instances.

I have the options as { db: { readPreference: secondaryPreferred } } and passing it to the function MongoClient.connect in the node.js code using native Mongo Driver.

The URL used to connect looks like mongodb://admin:pass@host_one:27017,host_two:27017,host_three:27017/dbName

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: If you connect to one of the nodes and run `rs.status()` is there actually a node which is running as master? Maybe one of the nodes is master or the RS is in a strange state and isn't nothing to do with the client.

Comment: It's showing proper status while running rs.status(). I did some debugging and it seems like its throwing an error while executing the drop collection call. The other commands seem to run fine.

Comment: The `db.collection.drop()` command returning an error `not master` when using `secondary` or `secondaryPreferred` read preference will be fixed in the upcoming MongoDB version 3.2.7. Please note that this issue only affects the `drop` command. Other write functions such as `insert`, `delete`, or `update` should work when using `secondaryPreferred` read preference.

Answer (score 4):

Did you add in your `replicaSet` name?

```
mongodb://admin:pass@host_one:27017,host_two:27017,host_three:27017/dbName?replicaSet=my-replica-set
```

> replicaSet=name
>
> The driver verifies that the name of the replica set it connects to
> matches this name. Implies that the hosts given are a seed list, and
> the driver will attempt to find all members of the set. No default
> value.

If this is not set it will be treated as a standalone node.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your replica set configuration is not correct.
To check the configuration run the `rs.conf()` command in your mongo servers. You need to have a mongo host running as `primary` member.

```sh
MongoError: Not master
```

This error seems like your primary member of replica set is not configured properly.

You can confirm this by entering into mongo shell of the `host_one`. If mongo shell prompt doesn't show `PRIMARY`, then it's not configured properly.

Mongo shell prompt of `host_two` and `host_three` should show `SECONDARY` after proper configuration.

> **Important** : Run `rs.initiate()` on just one and only one mongod instance for the replica set.

You can execute this command on the primary member to make the configuration work properly.

```js
rs.initiate();
cfg = {
    _id: 'rs0',
    members: [{
        _id: 0,
        host: 'host_one:27017',
        priority: 2
    }, {
        _id: 1,
        host: 'host_two:27017',
        priority: 1
    }, {
        _id: 2,
        host: 'host_three:27017',
        priority: 1
    }]
};
cfg.protocolVersion = 1;
rs.reconfig(cfg, {
    force: true
});
```

Please note that `priority` value indicates the relative eligibility of a member to become a primary.

> Specify higher values to make a member more eligible to become primary, and lower values to make the member less eligible. A member with a `priority` of 0 is ineligible to become primary.

You can again check your replica set configuration using this command

```
rs.conf()
```

Answer (score 0):

Read preference is not applicable to writes. Writes must always be performed on the primary.

You should be connecting to replica set instead of directly to an individual node. See [node.js mongodb how to connect to replicaset of mongo servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384735/node-js-mongodb-how-to-connect-to-replicaset-of-mongo-servers)